# Problems with inner join clause in symfony query builder

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I'm trying to retrieve data from a table using an inner join to filter the result with a param in a where clause, I show you my code:

```
#[Route('/api/movies/genre/{genre}')]
    public function listFiltered(Connection $db, $genre): Response
    {
        $query = $db->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select("m.*")
            ->from("movies", "m")
            ->innerJoin('m', 'movies_genres', 'mg', 'mg.movie_id = m.id')
            ->where('mg.genre_id =' ,$genre)
            ->setMaxResults(50)
            ->executeQuery()
            ->fetchAllAssociative();
        dd($query);
        return $this->json([
            "filtered" => $query
        ]);
    }
```

I pass $genre value from url route

My db structure is
movies:id, rank, release_data,title
movies_genres:movie_id,genre_id

my error is:
An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') AND (Action) LIMIT 50' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `where()` method with `:genre` placeholder, and `setParameter()` is used on the value of `$genre` which should prevent the syntax error and possible SQL injection issues:

```
$query = $db->createQueryBuilder()
  ->select("m.*")
  ->from("movies", "m")
  ->innerJoin('m', 'movies_genres', 'mg', 'mg.movie_id = m.id')
  ->where('mg.genre_id = :genre')
  ->setParameter('genre', $genre)
  ->setMaxResults(50)
  ->executeQuery()
  ->fetchAllAssociative();
```

If the above does not work, try debugging by echoing the generated SQL query using `$query->getSQL()` and checking for any syntax issues in that.